# Group by column change all text

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a database. I keep the physical IP addresses of the users, I keep the IP addresses as 1.2.3.4 but I want to update it without personal data like A-B-C-D-E-F and share it as open data.

For example, if there are 50 lines of records at the 1.2.3.4 IP address, it will say that 50 entries have been made from the A address, and if there are 150 records at the 2.3.4.5 IP address, it will say that they have made 150 entries from the B address.

For example in the photo below, it will write A-B-C-D-E-F instead of the full ip address.

This SQL Query;

```
SELECT IPADDRESS, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY IPADDRESS
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3bRY.png)

There are more than 50k rows, how can I do this with T-SQL?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: added example photo and description

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please provide your sample data as tabular text rather than as an image. It is also helpful to show the desired results, as a separate data table.

Comment: [Bad habits: putting `nolock` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: with(nolock) is changed, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach uses dense_rank; for example, this would assign a fixed, constant numeric value to each district IP address:

```
select t.*,
    dense_rank() over(order by ipaddress) anonymous_ipaddress
from mytable t
```

I find that using numbers is more sensible than letters (what do you do when you reach Z?). But if you really wanted to use a predefined list of unique ids, we could still enumerate them and join on the rank.

Comment: perfect query, it is work

Comment: Could convert it to hex if you wanted to densify it a bit